# How to extract conversion list of firbase push notifications?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need data of conversion from push notifications of Firebase but when download from report in csv format than conversion column is not there like below :

[image: data report downloaded from firebase]

but when i check every notification manually i saw conversion numbers like below :

[image: show conversion during manually checking]